# Pagination in Symfony2.4.2 With MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Hi Can anyone please let me know how to use pagination in Symfony2.4.2 while i am using MongoDB with symfony.I could not find any good way to do that like in Cakephp we can use its inbuilt component for  Pagination.

Following are my query in controller listing all task from Mongodb.

```
 $documents = $dm->getRepository('WorkOrganisationBundle:Tasks')->findAll();
            $counttasks = count($documents);
            return $this->render('WorkOrganisationBundle:Tasks:index.html.twig', array(
                            'documents' => $documents                        
                        ));
```

Thanks Advance

Comment: You may want to have a look at the KnpPaginatorBundle https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: I do not want to use any kind of bundle i want to do this as custom pagination